# insert new sequential records into child table for each record of parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (SQL-server):

```
t1 (parent)
===========
id
1
2
```

```
t2 (child)
=======================
parent_id record_number
1         1
2         1
2         2
```

Is it possible in one SQL statement to insert new records into t2 for each of parent id, so the result will be:

```
t2:
=======================
parent_id record_number
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         2
2         3
```

Thank you!

Comment: where is 1,2 and 2,3 coming from?

Comment: @SalmanA it would be the next sequential `record_number` for each `parent_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get what you want.

Note I added it with a LEFT JOIN so you could use ISNULL in case the parent record isn't in t2 yet.

```
INSERT INTO t2 (parent_id, record_number)
SELECT
    A.id,
    ISNULL(MAX(B.record_number), 0) + 1
FROM t1 A 
LEFT JOIN t2 B 
ON      A.id = B.parent_id
GROUP BY 
    A.id
```

As an aside, generating a record number could be done effectively using the ROW_NUMBER() function. Here is an example. Perhaps you have specific reasons why it needs to be persisted to the table, but if not this could be useful as well to calculate it on the fly.

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY id)
FROM t2 
ORDER BY parent_id, record_number
```

Note it assumes you have an "id" column in t2, or something else to order the records by

Comment: Dear Eilert Hjelmeseth, this is just what I need, thanks!

Thank you all answering my question!

Comment: @cadol_StOv, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what the OP is after is:

```
INSERT INTO T2
SELECT T1.id
       MAX(T2.ID) + 1
FROM T1
     JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.parent_id
GROUP BY T1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into t2 (parent_id, record_number)
    select id, id
    from t1;
```

If so, I prefer using `NULL` to represent that that something has no parent:

```
insert into t2 (parent_id, record_number)
    select null, id
    from t1;
```

This is a more accurate representation of the data.  Something is not its own parent.